# Error while opening, Native Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker, native

I have Mac 10.10.5, 
I have downloaded Docker native for Mac.
In spite of having admin access to my machine, I keep getting following error

```
Administrator privileges are required.
You need administrator privileges on this computer to install Docker. 
Please log in as an administrator to install the app, then you can use Docker  
with standard user accounts.
```

I used to have Docker Native Beta, few weeks back I tried upgrading it, and since then I started having this issue. 
Any idea why is this happening?